# Complete List of Commands of SELENIUM IDE

Tags: selenium, ide

I m new to selenium and in first phase i am trying hard to grasp IDE commands but the main problem that i m facing s that i m unable to search a Single helping material which clearly tell me the following points if any one knows kindly refer me

1. Complete List of Commands
2. Commands with reference to scenario(e.g when we use asserttext or
   verify text)
3. what will be the values  of Target and value.

Answer (score 3):

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html

This is the complete reference that contains

1. All the commands supported.
2. Descriptions to the methods including explanation of the difference between `assert` and `verify`.
3. The `target` is usually the locator of the element. The `value` is usually a parameter of the method - for instance, when you're typing into a field, the `value` would be the text you want to type in. More in the reference of every single command - not all the commands take both target and value, some have their values restricted etc. See your particular command to know what parameters it needs.

Anyway, the most helpful piece of documentation for IDE is still [the official docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp) even though they don't really have a list of all commnads.

Comment: This is not a correct reference. Some methods are deprecated now, and i can't find a valid one.

Comment: @smsteel I changed the link to a slightly newer version. I am not aware of any other document, though. Is it better?

Comment: I cannot open this link today

Comment: @NamGVU Unfortunately that's still where the official link from the official docs leads to. On the other hand, please consider carefully whether you still need the IDE. Times have changed, the development of Selenium 1 (Selenium RC and Selenium IDE) has stopped a long time ago, and Selenium WebDriver is the standard today. Much better, more robust, with better documentation...

Comment: Okie it's clearer now. May we highlight the unavailabe in you answer and remind others to use WebDriver too?

Answer (score 2):

1) If you are using the Selenium ide for firefox the full list of commands is visible by clicking the down arrow in the command section.

Failing that there should be plenty of useful information in the selenium documentation
    http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/index.jsp

2) This one I can't help with very much, as I generally use asserts everywhere. If i want my script to fail at a particular point if text is not present in java I use something like

```
assertTrue(driver.getPageSource.contains("Text to verify");
```

3) Target is the element and value is the current value of that element.
Example - Assert that text is present

```
Command - assertTextPresent
Target  - Blank
Value   - Text to search for
```

Example 2 - Field contains certain text

```
command - assertTextPresent
Target  - id=idOfField  (id, xpath, css, name etc)
Value   - Text to search for
```

Comment: if i left Target blank then it Selenium always passed my TC                    scenario

Comment: Hmm.. Like I say I usually only use selenium IDE to record the script the export to java to do my verification.

Comment: that fails because it's missing a closing paren :)

Answer (score 1):

http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/search/label/selenium%20ide

This website have a lot of IDE examples and tutorials. If you are beginner if so this website is the best I think.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most complete and most readable list of the selenium IDE commands:

> http://www.frontendtest.org/blog/selenium-ide-commands/